# Can you make an app display a local notification while it's open?

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

I've set up notifications with UNUserNotificationCenter but they're only displayed when the app isn't running. There's some older threads asking the same question but the answers to those aren't working for me so I'm wondering if there's an updated way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code triggers `local notification` when app is in foreground and background.

```
import UIKit
import UserNotifications

class ViewController: UIViewController, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //requesting for authorization
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge], completionHandler: {didAllow, error in
                if error == nil {
                    self.triggerLocalNotification()
            }
        })
    }

    func triggerLocalNotification(){

        //creating the notification content
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()

        //adding title, subtitle, body and badge
        content.title = "Notification title "
        content.subtitle = "Notification sub-title "
        content.body = "We are learning about iOS Local Notification"
        content.badge = 1

        //it will be called after 5 seconds
        let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 5, repeats: false)

        //getting the notification request
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "SimplifiedIOSNotification", content: content, trigger: trigger)

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

        //adding the notification to notification center
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

        //displaying the ios local notification when app is in foreground
        completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
    }
}
```

Comment: this one still only triggers when I'm not in the app - do you know whether it works in the simulator? Maybe it works on real devices but just isn't showing in the simulator

Comment: yes, it is working in simulator too when the app is in foreground.

Comment: Got it to work - for other people reading this, if it doesn't work for you, put ```UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self``` in viewDidLoad instead of the function.